# Resizing bitmap image within imageview

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have an `imageview` that displays a photo taken with the phone's camera, which can be changed by the user. The problem I'm having is that the picture is scaling too small within the `imageview`, is there a way to force the `bitmap` to fit the `imageview` completely?

Comment: use the scale attribute of the imageview.

Comment: Well that was a lot easier than I thought, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Next time, please search a few minutes, before you ask a question!*

---

In the layout xml-file you have to add the following attributes to your ImageView to make it fill out the view:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

You can find the attribute in the [ImageView documentation's list of XML Attributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#lattrs). The different scaleTypes can then be found by clicking ["android:scaleType" to get to its description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType).

Comment: Ye sorry I did some looking around and I must have been searching for the wrong thing because nothing came up. Thanks.

Comment: It's ok. ;) Just wanted to make clear how important it is to search before asking. I know how hard it can be. ;)